# WinJS.UI Metro Animation Library

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm starting to port over my web app that I've built with Sencha Touch into the Windows 8 world. I'm seeing a lot of `WinJS.UI` documentation, basically telling me that there are more 'native' feeling animations and UI actions already build into this framework.

My app is already structured, but I'd like to mix in `WinJS.UI` if I can. How do I go about doing this? I haven't found a link to download the library or anything of the sort.

For example, this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/01/fast-and-fluid-animations-in-your-metro-style-app.aspx

I see that they are using:

```
<script>       
   function runAnimation(){
      enterPage = WinJS.UI.Animation.enterPage(input);
   }
</script>
```

But I find no documentation on where to include the library.

Little bit lost, any help is appreciated!

Comment: As it seems to be hard to find good description of how to animate page transitions with WinJS.Animation, I will link to related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009102/how-do-you-animate-navigation-in-windows-8-metro-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These animations are included in the UI.Js from the WinJS Package -- this is the same WinJS that is included in the default Visual Studio Templates. Just create a new HTML Windows Store application, and the details will be there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do these come with the Visual Studio SDK for Windows Phone? Do I need the full version of VS to get these examples?

Comment: These are in the Visual Studio 2012 Express For Windows 8, or any of the full version. These are for HTML apps; Windows Phone doesn't support those apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your library: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-the-Animation-787f3720

You can deploy this on your computer and play with the animations.

Comment: This needs to be loaded as a Visual Studio project, correct? I can't just play with the HTML/CSS/JS by itself?

Comment: Yeah but you can set up a new project to basically handle all the creating for you.